# how to remove warning from console?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Used redux, react and [material-ui lib](https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
I have react component which use react and redux. State received from redux, so,
this component:

```
import React from "react";
import {withStyles} from "material-ui/styles";
import {MenuItem} from "material-ui/Menu";
import Chip from "material-ui/Chip";
import CancelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Cancel";
import Input from "material-ui/Input";
import Select from "react-select";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;

const styles = theme => ({
  // Autocomplete styles
  "@global": {
    ".Select-control": {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      border: 0,
      height: "auto",
      background: "transparent",
      "&:hover": {
        boxShadow: "none",
      },
    },
    ".Select-multi-value-wrapper": {
      flexGrow: 1,
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
    },
    ".Select--multi .Select-input": {
      margin: 0,
    },
    ".Select.has-value.is-clearable.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value": {
      padding: 0,
    },
    ".Select-noresults": {
      padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
    ".Select-input": {
      display: "inline-flex !important",
      padding: 0,
      height: "auto",
    },
    ".Select-input input": {
      background: "transparent",
      border: 0,
      padding: 0,
      cursor: "default",
      display: "inline-block",
      fontFamily: "inherit",
      fontSize: "inherit",
      margin: 0,
      outline: 0,
    },
    ".Select-placeholder, .Select--single .Select-value": {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily,
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(16),
      padding: 0,
    },
    ".Select-placeholder": {
      opacity: 0.42,
      color: theme.palette.common.black,
    },
    ".Select-menu-outer": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      boxShadow: theme.shadows[2],
      position: "absolute",
      left: 0,
      top: `calc(100% + ${theme.spacing.unit}px)`,
      width: "100%",
      zIndex: 2,
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 7.7,
    },
    ".Select.is-focused:not(.is-open) > .Select-control": {
      boxShadow: "none",
    },
    ".Select-menu": {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 7.7,
      overflowY: "auto",
    },
    ".Select-menu div": {
      boxSizing: "content-box",
    },
    ".Select-arrow-zone, .Select-clear-zone": {
      color: theme.palette.action.active,
      cursor: "pointer",
      height: 21,
      width: 21,
      zIndex: 1,
    },
    ".Select-aria-only": {
      position: "absolute",
      overflow: "hidden",
      clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
      height: 1,
      width: 1,
      margin: -1,
    },
    autocomlete: {
      paddingBottom: 30,
      marginRight: 20,
      fontWeight: 200,
      paddingRight: 20,
      width: 750,
    },
  },
});

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const Option = ({isFocused, isSelected, onFocus = () => {}, children = [], onSelect = () => {}, option}) => {
  const handleClick = event => onSelect(option, event);
  return (
    <MenuItem
      onFocus={onFocus}
      selected={isFocused}
      onClick={handleClick}
      component="div"
      style={{fontWeight: isSelected ? 500 : 400}}
    >
      {children}
    </MenuItem>
  );
};

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const SelectWrapped = (props) => {
  const {classes, ...other} = props;
  return (
    <Select
      optionComponent={Option}
      noResultsText={<Typography>No results found</Typography>}
      valueComponent={(valueProps) => {
        const {value, children, onRemove} = valueProps;
        const onDelete = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          onRemove(value);
        };
        if (onRemove) {
          return (
            <Chip
              tabIndex={-1}
              label={children}
              className={classes.chip}
              deleteIcon={<CancelIcon onTouchEnd={onDelete}/>}
              onDelete={onDelete}
            />
          );
        }
        return <div className="Select-value">{children}</div>;
      }}
      {...other}
    />
  );
};

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const Autocomplete = ({items = [], handleChange, selectedItems = [], multi, changeSelectionActionName}) => (
  <div className={styles.autocomlete}>
    <Input
      fullWidth
      inputComponent={SelectWrapped}
      value={selectedItems}
      onChange={handleChange(changeSelectionActionName)}
      placeholder="Выберите из списка или начните вводить название"
      name="react-select-chip"
      inputProps={{
        multi,
        classes: styles,
        instanceId: "react-select-chip",
        id: "react-select-chip",
        options: items.map(item => ({value: item.id, label: item.name})),
      }}
    />
  </div>);

export default withStyles(styles)(Autocomplete);
```

So, it works okey, I can selecte items, changes are shows, but, when I first time click on autocomplete, there is waring message in console:

```
    warning.js:1 Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Check the render method of `Select`.
    in Option (created by Select)
    in div (created by Select)
    in div (created by Select)
    in div (created by Select)
    in Select (created by SelectWrapped)
    in SelectWrapped (created by Input)
    in div (created by Input)
    in Input (created by WithStyles(Input))
    in WithStyles(Input) (created by Autocomplete)
    in div (created by Autocomplete)
    in Autocomplete (created by WithStyles(Autocomplete))
    in WithStyles(Autocomplete) (created by DivisionReport)
    in span (created by DivisionReport)
    in div (created by DivisionReport)
    in DivisionReport (created by WithStyles(DivisionReport))
    in WithStyles(DivisionReport) (created by OvertimesReport)
    in div (created by Typography)
    in Typography (created by WithStyles(Typography))
```

So, how to remove this warning message from console?

Comment: Try converting your function component into a class component

Answer (score 6):

[image]

that will remove all warnings from your console.
my advice would be to leave it on and handle your error. apparently `react-select` needs to be wrapped in class component.

Comment: But if I use redux for store param-states, how can I to interact with redux-storage from class-component? F.e. I change selected elements, so list of selected items I need to pass in store..

Comment: you `mapStateToProps` and `connect` your component with store. you can read more about it here https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact